# How to install Ada IDE on mac (OSX)?

Tags: macos, ide, ada

1. Downloaded the GNAT Ada GPL 2015
2. Unpacked it
3. Clicked the doinstall
4. Followed the steps it provides.

However, finally my terminal told me

> "no rule to make target 'ins-all' "

and

> "an error occurred during installation".

I got confused and would you like to help me out?

Comment: I repeated your steps and got the same result. So it’s not just that you don’t have the Xcode Command Line Tools installed! Try running the installation from the command line by (a) opening a Terminal window, and (b) **typing** `./doinstall` [RET]

Comment: I meant, of course, opening a Terminal window *at the directory in which `doinstall` is located*.

Comment: Yeyy! Thank u very much.